# IC to switch 16 LEDs digitally?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, control

I made a circuit with 16 transistors which switch 16 LEDs, input signal is from raspberry (or any board) digitally.

But is was difficult to solder and I tried to keep it as small as possible.

In the end there are still a few switches who do not work.
So I put that aside and tried with smaller amounts, ie. four

But meanwhile it came to my mind, maybe there are ICs who can do that job much easier??

Comment: *In the end there are still a few switches who do not work. So I put that aside and tried with smaller amounts, ie. four* It is completely unclear to me what you're trying to say in that sentence. If you want to show what you did, include a schematic.

Comment: "input signal is from raspberry (or any board)"  The amount you can drive is going to depend on the device.  So you can't "or any board" and get the same drive capability.  It will depend on the specific board.

Answer (score 3):

May be IS31FL3216 is what you are looking for.

http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31FL3216.pdf

It can support 16LEDs to be controlled with 20mA current in 256 steps.

Comment: This chip sounds also useful, Brightness control is nice. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are, you can use e.g.:

- Multiplexers, like 74HC595. They can drive 8 LEDs (but not on full strength); you can daisy chain them to drive 16, 24 or 32 and use SPI as communication protocol.
- Darlington Transistor Array ICs, like ULN2803 (there are more types, ULN2803 is just an example).
- Also there are dedicated LED driver ICs (but don't know a specific ID number).